# How does chaining operators in javascript work?

Tags: javascript

I was looking to XOR three boolean variables. Only one can be true, and one must be true:

```
function isValid(a, b, c) { return a !== b !== c; }

var one = false;
var two = false;
var three = true;

console.log(isValid(one, two, three)); // should be true  

one = true;
console.log(isValid(one, two, three)); // should be false
```

This solution seems to work, but my question is... why? Shouldn't it fail if all values are false?

```
var one = false;
var two = false;
var three = false;
console.log(isValid(one, two, three)); // should be true, but it is false
```

Additionally, all variables being true, returns true when it should return false.

```
var one = true;
var two = true;
var three = true;
console.log(isValid(one, two, three)); // should be false, but it's true
```

My thought is that it executes thusly:

```
a    !== b?  TRUE
TRUE !== c?  TRUE
```

Clearly that isn't how it works, so how does it work?

Comment: JavaScript is not like Python. `a !== b !== c` means `(a !== b) !== c`, and `(a !== b)` yields a boolean value, and that value is what's compared to `c`.

Comment: If they're all true, it outputs true as well

Comment: `a !== b` this is `false`, since both elements have the value `false`. Then you get `false !== c`, which is also `false`, since `c` has the value `false`. So your solution does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @Shilly I was going to check for what I think is just the edge case of all of them being true, but is there a better way?

Comment: In the same vein, if all are `true`, you get `( true !== true )`, which is false. And then `false !== true`, which is true.

Comment: Bottom line is this: you want `a !== b && a !== c && b !== c`

Comment: Ah... Thanks @Pointy. I asked it over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714740/how-to-xor-three-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This solution seems to work, but my question is... why?

It *doesn't* work for what you described (only one can be true, and one must be true); it fails in the `true, true, true` case:

```js
function isValid(a, b, c) { return a !== b !== c; }

console.log(isValid(true, true, true)); // true, should be false
```

I should note that I don't think your rule is quite the same as XOR, since `true XOR true XOR true` is `true` (because `true XOR true` is `false`, and `false XOR true` is `true`).

`a !== b !== c` is evaluated like this:

- `a !== b` is evaluated and yields a `boolean` result, either `true` if the condition is true or `false` if it's false. Call that `r`. In the `true, true, true` case, `true !== true` is `false` so `r = false`.
- `r !== c` is evaluated and yields its `boolean` result. In the `true, true, true` case, `false !== true` is `true`.

As you can see from the above, it works in almost all XOR cases, but not when all the inputs are `true`. It also doesn't work for other examples. Probably the most common error people make is trying to see if `a`, `b`, and `c` all have the same value:

```
if (a === b === c) // WRONG (almost always)
```

Since that's `((a === b) === c)` which is `(some_boolean === c)`, it's almost always wrong (for instance, if `a`, `b`, and `c` contain anything but `boolean` values).

Comment: Thanks. I soon discovered all true got me the error. I came up with a solution, but I feel there is a better one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714740/how-to-xor-three-variables-in-javascript

Comment: @Jeff - Actually...now I think about it, `true XOR true XOR true` *should* be `true`, because `true XOR true` is `false`, and `false XOR true` is `true`. It just happens that for this **particular** operation, `a !== b !== c` produces the expected result for XOR (but not for what you said you wanted). But you can't generalize that... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since the operator are of same precedence so the `Associativity` decides how this is going to be evaluate  [`Operator precedence`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

```
function isValid(a, b, c) { return a !== b !== c; }

var one = false;
var two = false;
var three = true;
```

You can understand it step by step

```
   a !== b   -> this return `false` as false !== false
```

so now the condition is

```
 false !== c  -> this return `true` as false !== true
```