# How to xor three variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Related to my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714546/how-does-chaining-operators-in-javascript-work), how would you xor three boolean variables in javascript. One variable can be true the rest must be false.

This is my solution, but I feel there is a better one:

```
function isValid(a, b, c) {
  return (a !== b ! == c) && [a, b, c].includes(false);
}
```

I've gotten some feed back from the comments, let me define what I'm asking (sorry for all the confusion).

1. I'm actually doing this in a typescript class. I figured I'd just remove the method and make it a classless function. I realize now that this does affect the solution. Sorry about that.
2. I suppose I must have missused the term XOR. What I'm trying to say is, only a OR b OR c can be true, and one of them must be true. I hope that is more clear.

Comment: Something like `[a, b, c].filter(x => !!x).length === 1`?

Comment: What exactly is `isValid()` supposed to mean? The function here doesn't really make any obvious sense.

Comment: `true XOR true XOR true` is `true`, not `false`. `true XOR true` is `false`, and `false XOR true` is `true`.

Comment: @Pointy Doesn't the text of the question clarify? "One variable can be true, the rest must be false"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think his mention of XOR was just confused generalization. He explained what he really wants in the text.

Comment: @Barmar - I think it needs clarifying, since it significantly changes the answers whether he really wants XOR or really wants what he described.

Comment: See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714740/how-to-xor-three-variables-in-javascript#comment101871728_57714840) (very interesting!).

Comment: @Barmar well I don't think that's what his implementation does, and furthermore it's questionable JavaScript style to write a function that assumes the parameters passed will be actual boolean values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If these are boolean values, just filter and test that only one is true:

```
function isValid(...args) {
  return args.filter(v => v).length == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was working on a similar solution in the prev question. This one works with as many booleans as you want.

`.includes()` makes sure that `true` is in the array.
and comparing the index and lastIndex tells you if it's the only `true`.

This does assume that XOR is `exactly one true among all booleans checked.`

```js
const xor = ( ...booleans ) => ( booleans.includes( true ) && booleans.indexOf( true ) === booleans.lastIndexOf( true ));

console.log( xor( ...[ true, true, true, true, true ]), false );
console.log( xor( ...[ false, false, false, false, false ]), false );
console.log( xor( ...[ true, true, false, false, false ]), false );
console.log( xor( ...[ false, true, false, false, false ]), true );
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but that definition of XOR is completely wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was wondering, but the OP asked for `there should be one true value and only one.`. So this will fix the OPs problem, but it might not be called XOR.

Comment: That's right, but the question is asking for something that is expressly not XOR despite their claims to the contrary.

Comment: Yeah, all of this is a bit confusing since we continued from out of the previous question.

Comment: @tadman Turns out, there are two opposing definitions of multi-input xor. One is that an odd number of inputs should be true, the other is that exactly 1 input should be true. More info: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/93719

Comment: @IceMetalPunk That's an interesting find, but that also suggests using "odd parity" as a term for that particular operation instead of the widely understood meaning of XOR in terms of boolean arithmetic.

Comment: @tadman It think it was using "odd parity" as the term for the usual "odd number of trues" definition, not the "exactly 1 true" definition.

Comment: I had no idea that there were two definitions of XOR. Fascinating.

Answer (score 4):

You have to be careful in JavaScript because expressions that *look* like boolean expressions may not return boolean values. The "logical" operators `&&` and `||` perform a boolean interpretation of their left-side and right-side operands, but the ultimate value is the *actual* value as it was before the boolean interpretation.

If you want a function that interprets its arguments as booleans, and returns a value indicating the result of an XOR, then it might be simplest to do that explicitly:

```
function isValid(a, b, c) {
  return !!(+!!a ^ +!!b ^ +!!c);
}
```

That performs a "to boolean" operation (`!!`) on each parameter, followed by a "to number" (`+`).  Then the three numbers are XORed with `^`, and the result converted back to boolean and returned.

The "to boolean" operation implicitly performs the same interpretation as

```
if (something)
```

does; that is, the value, whatever it happens to be, is determined to be either "truthy" or "falsy", and the result expressed as either `true` or `false`.  Converting a boolean value to a number then yields either 0 or 1.

Comment: You don't need those `!!`, the coercion will be implicit with `!!(a ^ b ^ c)`. But note that the OP's rules don't match XORs rules.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's for pedagogical clarity :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder also I don't fully understand what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Fair enough. :-) For this record, this (well, the version in my comment above) was exactly what I was going to do until I realized that XOR doesn't match what he described. This does XOR. It's unclear to me whether he really wants it or not. He may. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your arguments are guaranteed to be boolean, it's enough to sum them and compare the result with 1:

```
let hasOneTrue = (...values) => values.reduce((x, y) => x + y) === 1
```

For arbitrary values, add the `Boolean` typecast (or `!!` if feeling hacky)

```
let hasOneTrue = (...values) => values.reduce((x, y) => x + Boolean(y), 0) === 1
```

For the sake of completeness,

```
let hasOneFalse = (...values) => values.reduce((x, y) => x + y) === values.length - 1
```

Since you mention typescript in your edit:

```
let hasOneTrue = (values: [boolean]): boolean => values.reduce((x, y) => x + (y ? 1 : 0) , 0) === 1
```

Comment: `true + false == 1` is one of those wild JavaScript things isn't it?

Comment: @tadman: boolean being a subclass of number is not that uncommon, cf. python

Answer (score 0):

When using XOR with 3 variables you get a `true` condition in 2 cases 
1:when only one of the variables is true
2:when all the variables is true.
The condition where only one variable is true works for 2 variables. So the solution to your query would be.

```
function xor(a,b,c){
  if(a && b && c){
    return false //You have to make an exception for all conditions being true
   }
  return ((a && !b && !c) || (!a && b && !c) || (!a && !b && c) || (a && b && c))
}

console.log(xor(true,true,true)) //false
console.log(xor(true,true,false)) //false
console.log(xor(true,false,false)) //true
```