# JS syntax for "if a or b or c but not all of them"

Tags: javascript, typescript

So, I am super new to JS! I am trying to write a syntax to check if only one of the three variable is present.

```
if a and (not b or not c) or b and (not a or not c) or c and (not a or not b)
```

Comment: [TS version](https://tsplay.dev/Na292m) of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57714874/438273) at the duplicate question link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert them to booleans, then add them up, and check that the result is 1. (true will be coerced to 1; false will be coerced to 0.)

```
if (Number(Boolean(a)) + Number(Boolean(b)) + Number(Boolean(c)) === 1) {
  // ...
}
```

or

```
const sum = [a, b, c].reduce((sum, item) => sum + Number(Boolean(item)), 0);
if (sum === 1) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of coercing can't we do like this `if(Number(Boolean(a)) + Number(Boolean(b)) + Number(Boolean(c)) === 1)`.

Comment: Sure, if you want

Comment: @Shrey That is correct. [The code in the current iteration of this answer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwgVzQBMQAzdEQiAXggHJ4B7AWxAWXQ1oG4AoUSAEZxEqTDnxFS5Qr34QAxsPZjcBYmTQVePFCQgAKAEIMGoKGn1QAlBADUEY6ZDn9Am-cdmL8m1T8QARhsAbx4ICAB6CIgAOjieAF8gA) does not compile: `Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'boolean'.(2365)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
if ((a || b || c) && !(a && b && c)) {

}
```

Here's a test:

```js
function specialBool(a, b, c, message){
  if ((a || b || c) && !(a && b && c)) {
    console.log(message)
  }
}

specialBool(true, false, false, 'One true');
specialBool(true, true, false, 'Two true');
specialBool(true, true, true, 'All true'); // Shouldn't log
```